# font color text field content type

Tags: nodes

I have a text field in a content type which the user should be able to choose the color of the text.
Is there a module that I can install when creating the node you can choose the font color of the text field.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of this being possibly would be to make it a textarea multiple rows then add an wysiwyg editor to it.